# How to remove this space in editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my code for xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_smoke"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include layout="@layout/header" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAddContact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_trans"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/plus_text"
                android:textColor="@color/white_smoke"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/header_date"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbDownline"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/btn_radio_selector"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/rb_downline"
                android:textColor="@color/my_holo_text" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbCustomer"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/btn_radio_selector"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/rb_customer"
                android:textColor="@color/my_holo_text" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edSearchBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_ed_bg"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
            android:hint="@string/search_contacts"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="@color/my_holo_trans" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listContacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_list_view_round"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#149DCF"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_match_holo"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This xml shows output as following image,

[image]

As you can see that I am displaying an image in EditText box. I want to remove those padding type space ( marked as red ).

What should I do to remove it ?

Comment: Have you tried using `android:padding="0dp"` for `EditText` and `android:margin="0dp"` for `Button`?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it.

Comment: @SimplePlan, code uploaded

Comment: removing padding will definitely remove that extra space. if still not  removed, then check your image. your drawable will be having extra space.

Comment: `off topic` !!!!! seriously....

Comment: @user2060383 ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:drawablePadding="-2dip"
```

or whatever value do you need. Since you are using the `drawableLeft` item, you need the `drawablePadding` item as well, to adjust its padding

Comment: Yup, its working with -5dip, but now I have some space left from top of the image, which is not getting removed.

Comment: are you sure that your image has not a transparent area around it ?

Comment: Yes, it has some transparent area. I use Android Assets studio to create this image but by default it has some space which I cant remove manually.

Comment: well, you actually can. you can use Gimp, for instance, to cut the transparent area.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove padding from your edit text.Use below code:-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edSearchBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_ed_bg"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
    android:hint="@string/search_contacts"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/my_holo_trans" />
```

Comment: @user2060383 android:layout_height="30dp" try this code after using this let me know

Answer (score 0):

remove padding

```
 android:padding="8dp"
```